# Как достать из БД параметризированый список

Tags: java, sql, веб-программирование, postgresql, spring

у меня есть сущность Question:

```java
public class Question {
private Long id;
private Integer position;
private String question;
```

для этой сущности есть QuestionResponseDto:

```java
public class QuestionResponseDto {
private Long id;
private Integer position;
private String question;
```

требуется получить список состоящий из QuestionResponseDto запросом в БД

в ДАО слое я попытался реализовать этот метод, но у меня ничего не возвращается

```java
public List<QuestionResponseDto> getListOfQuestions() {
   return entityManager.createQuery("select new com.example.QuestionResponseDto(q.id, q.position, q.question) from Question q", 
           QuestionResponseDto.class).getResultList();
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не скриншотами

Comment: Мне кажется, ты не совсем понимаешь назначение паттерна DTO. Этот паттерн используется, когда у одной и той же сущности может быть несколько представлений на стороне пользователя или представление на стороне пользователя часто меняется. Могу также предположить, что ты пытаешься реализовать паттерн CQRS, но использование различных ORM (тем более реализующих JPA) плохо для этого подходит.
Поэтому, просто доставай из репозитория список Question, затем преобразуй его в список QuestionResponseDto.